# Kotlin Spring repository Inheritance problems when trying to override function

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I will try to simplify for the sake of clarity.
This is my Entities.kt where I have just two classes, A and B. B extends A

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "core")
open class A(
    @Id
    @Indexed(name="id", type = "string_or")
    var id: String = "",

    @Indexed(name="type", type = "string"
    var type: String = ""
)
open class B(
  @Indexed(name="b_field", type= "string")
  var bField: String = ""
) : A()
```

In my Repositories.kt I tried to replicate this inheritance model, and then I'm trying to override the findAll function of Repository B, so that only those objects of type B are returned, like this:

```
interface BaseRepository<T: A>: SolrCrudRepository<T, String> {
    fun findByType(type: String): List<T>
}

interface ARepository: BaseRepository<A> {

}

interface BRepository: BaseRepository<B> {
   @Query("type:B")
   override fun findAll(): List<B>
}
```

However, when calling findAll from the controller, I still receive all the objects (regardless of type A or B), this is my code in the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/B")
class BController(private val repository: BRepository) {

  @GetMapping("")
  fun findAll() = repository.findAll()
}
```

I've also tried doing a similar thing using just JPA instead of Solr but I have the same problem, the parent (default) findAll function is executed instead of the overriden function. Any ideas?